# SP 2007 - Access Denied for Site Collection Admins + everyone else

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2007, access, denied

SP 2007 (yes MOSS 2007) - I've been checking a MOSS 2007 web app lately and it seems it is for some reasons throwing Access Denied for everyone, including the Site Collection Admins. Just wondered if anyone could share some thoughts on that and possibly provide some direction please? I have checked things like Content DB, SC Locks and changed Site Collection Admins too etc. and everything seems to be in its place but the issue not resolved.

Any Information shared will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try couple of things to fix the problem

- try to add the users into the Web Application policy...this will give that user full control on the site then you can test the site. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262737(v=office.12).aspx
- Check the ULS logs to get the clue on which page Access denied occurred.
- Check on the SQL server, If Content DB locked or SQL drive running out of space.
- Also check if you have any custom solution / customization applied to the farm which is breaking the things.